# SELECT ... WHERE col1 in (input1, input2) how to know which not found?

Tags: sql, postgresql

`SELECT col2 FROM table WHERE col1 in (input1, input2, input3)`

If resulted in only one value, how to know which (input1, input2 or input3) were not found in col1?

It should be something like `SELECT ? FROM (input1, input2, input3) WHERE ? NOT IN col1 FROM table`, but couldn't find anything.

By the way, I use PostgeSQL.

Comment: I guess  `SELECT col2 FROM table WHERE col1 not in (input1, input2, input3)` could slove your problem.

Comment: It results in whole database col2 entries except the input that coincidence

Comment: null associated with input index would be good. The most useful result would have form like (null, col2_value, null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with v(x) as (values(input1),(input2),(input3))
select v.x from v except select col1 from table;
```

or

```
with v(x) as (values(input1),(input2),(input3))
select distinct v.x from v left join table on (v.x = table.col1)
where table.col1 is null;
```

or

```
with v(x) as (values(input1),(input2),(input3))
select v.x from v
where not exists (select 1 from table where table.col1 = v.x)
```

Last one is most efficient I think.

Instead of `values(input1),(input2),(input3)` you could to use arrays:

```
with v(x) as (select unnest(array[input1,input2,input3])) ...
```

or

```
with v(x) as (select unnest('{input1,input2,input3}'::input_type[])) ...
```

to be able to pass the various number of input values from your application without rewrite the query.